# Does the top quark decay into an on-shell W boson?

Tags: quarks, weak-interaction, bosons

Considering that the top/truth quark is the only quark with higher mass than the massive bosons, is the W boson in its decay different than the off-shell bosons that mediate the weak decay of other particles?

Answer (score 1):

My usual disclaimer: I use these questions as a way of learning for myself  about different aspects of physics, so please view this as an **attempt**, rather than as an answer in itself.

The top quark is the only quark heavy enough to decay into an on-shell W boson, usually accompanied by a bottom quark. We observe a jet containing the bottom quark decay products, $e_{\nu} $,  $\mu_{\nu} $,  $\tau_{\nu} $.

[image]

Image source for all images displayed: T.Tait Talk.pdf

Decays into other possible candidate such as  strange or down quarks are suppressed by the small [Cabibbo–Kobayashi–Maskaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabibbo%E2%80%93Kobayashi%E2%80%93Maskawa_matrix) matrix elements $V_{ts}$ and $V_{td}$

As the decay into $W_b $ is found to occur on nearly every occasion, we can then chart the decay of the weak boson into a branching ratios are 1:1:1:6 (jets). This ratio is 11% each for the neutrinos listed above and 67% for jets.

Three notable aspects of the top quark decay process:

1. The CKM elements are almost diagonal.
2. The W coupling constants are identical.
3. The light fermion masses are almost all small compared to the $M_W $ (mass of the W boson).

Top decay is a left handed interaction, using [Dirac /Gamma matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices)

$$\gamma^\mu (I -\gamma_5) $$

In a charged lepton decay, the lepton exhibits a tendency to move on the direction of top polarisation.

[image]

Comment: This might be implied by your original answer, but I am still curious. Do you know if the W in top decay behaves differently, that is, it decays in other ways than an off-shell W boson? My impression is that off-shell Ws' decays are dictated by the original particle, and bound by conservation of *its* properties. Whereas the on-shell W has its own physical properties and can decay correspondingly. What do you think?